# Change decimal and thousand marker in birt

Tags: sql, oracle, marker, birt

i make same report with birt but i'have to switch decimal marker and thousand marker.
For example i need to view this number '1.234,56' in this form '1,234.56'.
I search a way to do that using number format of birt, because i lost precision in number if i using for example the Oracle sql istruction

```
to_char(number, '999,990.99')
```

because i don't want to determine the length of the number for all my report number.

Sorry for my poor english but i need help.

Answer (score 1):

[NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/initparams129.htm) specifies characters that are used as group and decimal separators. You can change the `NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS` setting for the session(using `alter session`) or for the operation. In this case you can specify NLS setting as the third parameter of `to_char` function.

- `,` as decimal separator; `.` as group separator

  ```
    SQL> select to_char(123456.12, 'fm999G990D99', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS=,.') res
     2    from dual
     3  ;

     RES
     -----------
     123.456,12
  ```
- `.` as decimal separator; `,` as group separator

  ```
   SQL> select to_char(123456.12, 'fm999G990D99', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS=.,') res
     2    from dual
     3  ;

   RES
   -----------
   123,456.12
  ```

Comment: thanks Nicholas, but i don't want to reproduce the query...i want to change the view of data only in birt because there is the possibility of incosistent data if i use this data with other locale setting..

Comment: @AfanfeFana `NLS` setting used in `to_char` function will affect only the values passed in it, nothing more.

Comment: ok but i don't know nothing abuot the length of the number..i can't assume nothing about that, for example how much 9 have to put in the string formatter..and in last analysis i need to put in my report number and not String..
thank to help m..